# Method to pull from WCF to a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, wcf, visual-studio, ssis

I am looking for the easiest method to pull data from a WCF and load it into a SQL Server database.

I have a request for some data in our database. To learn EF I created a Entity Model based on a view that pulls the data (`v_report_all_clients`). I created the WCF service based on that model and tested it with a simple WPF datagrid. The WCF service exports a collection of `v_report_all_clients` objects which easily load into the simple data grid.

The user requesting the data is going to load the results into their database. I believe they have access to SSIS packages but I'm not sure using SSIS is the easiest method. I tried two approaches and neither were successful let alone easy. Briefly the methods I tried are:

1. Use Web Service Task - This works but unless I missed something you have to send the output to an XML file which seems like a wasteful middle step.
2. Use a Script Component - I am running into various issues trying to get this to work even after I follow some online examples. I can try to fight through the issues is this ends up being the best method but I am still not sure if this is the easiest. Plus the online examples didn't include the next logical step of loading into a database.

This is my first attempt to use a WCF as a means to distribute data from our database to various users. I'd like to leverage this technology for some of our larger web based reports that end up being almost an entire table dump. But if the users cannot easily integrate the WCF output into something they can use then I might have stick with web based reporting.

Comment: Have you looked at WCF Data Services?

Comment: I'm not sure that making my WCF service a WCF data service will change anything. The methods I used would be the same and they don't seem to be efficient. Is there something I'm missing about a WCF data service that would make the transition into SQL Server easier?

Comment: I did some research and I can see why a WCF Data Service or Web API solution would be easier. I had to install a package to get the OData provider in SSIS but with that I simply enter the URL and I can pipe results anywhere. There is no need for a script task or an intermediate flat file. Good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the idea given by [preet sangha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/30225/preet-sangha) is the best answer. I've experimented with a few possible solutions and I think a WCF Data Service is the easiest solution. After installing the OData add-on package for SSIS I was able to pipe the WCF Data Service directly to another table (or any other SSIS destination). It was very simple and easy in my opinion.

I think a second place vote might go to Web API which will give you more flexibility and control. The problem is that comes at a price of requiring more effort. I am also finding some quirks in Web API scaffolding.

Answer (score 0):

WCF services generally do not "contain" any data. From your description I am assuming the data you want to pull is probably contained in a SQL database somewhere on the lan/wan.

If it's in a database, and you want to put it in another database, then there is already a technology for doing that, it's called SSIS, which you're already using.

So my solution would be: don't use WCF for this task.

If you're going outside the local lan/wan for the data, then there are [other](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151763%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) [ways](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152569%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) to replicate the data locally.

Appreciate this does not answer your question as asked.

**EDIT**

Uncertain how database ownership "chaining" works - but suffice to say that either of the two methods you're proposing above (built in task or script task) both would appear to be eminently feasible. I am not a SSIS guru so would struggle to make a recommendation as to which one to use.

However by introducing a wcf service call into a ETL process you need to bear a few things in mind:

- You are introducing an out-of-process call with potentially large performance implications. WCF is not a lightweight stack - opening a channel takes seconds rather than the milliseconds it takes to open a DB connection.
- WCF service calls fail all the time. Handling timeouts and errors on the service side will need to be planned into your ETL process.
- If you want to "leverage the service for other uses", you may need to put quite a lot of upfront time into making sure the service contract is useful, coherent, and extensible - this is time you would not have to spend going direct to the data.

Hope this has helped you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. To clarify, I am exploring WCF for a few reasons. First, to learn and maybe leverage for other uses. But I also went down the path because when trying to grant the user access to the data they needed we ran into the issue on database ownership chaining. So I thought I might be able to use WCF to accomplish a few goals at once.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. In my research I have not seen where WCF calls fail often so that is something I will have to look into. While putting more upfront time into the service might be true over direct access, direct access will cause grief from a security configuration issue due to the DB ownership chaining issues. Learning about WCF is something I can leverage into other things like MVC while DB ownership chainning just allows me to finish a task and can't be leveraged.